# Unable to locate library liboleaut32 in Linux Mint 15

Tags: linux, qt, build, ld, gcc4.7

I'm using Mint 15, I'm a total noob when it comes to compiling softwares, but I'm trying to compile the "infinite-qt" GUI from the Git repo.
I managed to get "infinitecoind"(daemon) compiled, using the 'Makefile.unix' file.
What I'm trying to do now is to get the "infinitecoin-qt GUI" working. 
I think it kinda compiles alright to the point where I get this error message:

**build/qrc_bitcoin.o    -L/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu -lrt -lssl -lcrypto -ldb_cxx -loleaut32 -lboost_system -lboost_filesystem -lboost_program_options -lboost_thread -lQtGui - lQtCore -lpthread**

/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -loleaut32
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: ** [infinitecoin-qt] Error 1

Seems like it's some kind of lib missing somehow related to Windows, but I can't find it.
Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

`oleaut32` is a library used by Microsoft for OLE technologies - you won't be able to link against it on Linux...

see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa268922(v=vs.60).aspx